# ItemDecoration based on viewtype in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have multiple *view types* in my `RecyclerView` and I want to add an `ItemDecoration` based on the views type. Is there a way to do this?

This will add a decoration to every element:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
```

I saw this [library](https://github.com/magiepooh/RecyclerItemDecoration) but it supports only `LinearLayoutManager` vertical or horizontal, but I am using `GrildLayoutManager` and I use drawables for dividers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, you can.

If you draw the decoration yourself, you can distinguish between different view types in `getItemOffsets`  and `onDraw` by accessing the same method on the adapter like this:

```
// get the position
int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
// get the view type
int viewType = parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position);
```

Using this, you can draw your decoration only for your selected views. By accessing `getLeft()` and `getRight()` that code supports `GridLayout` as well as `LinearLayout`, to support *horizontal* alignment, the drawing just has to be done on the right side using the same approach.

In the end, you would create a decoration like the following:

```
public class DividerDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final Paint mPaint;
    private int mHeightDp;

    public DividerDecoration(Context context) {
        this(context, Color.argb((int) (255 * 0.2), 0, 0, 0), 1f);
    }

    public DividerDecoration(Context context, int color, float heightDp) {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        mHeightDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, heightDp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        int viewType = parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position);
        if (viewType == MY_VIEW_TYPE) {
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mHeightDp);
        } else {
            outRect.setEmpty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            int viewType = parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position);
            if (viewType == MY_VIEW_TYPE) {
                c.drawRect(view.getLeft(), view.getBottom(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom() + mHeightDp, mPaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a similar [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/bleeding182/recyclerviewItemDecorations/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/bleeding182/recyclerviewdecorations/DividerDecoration.java) with a demo project, which will not draw before or after header views or at the very end.

Comment: @user3531883 I think you need to be more detailed. The above code will help you distinguish between different view types, and you can draw your decoration based on that.

Comment: how to draw my decoration based on viewtype

Comment: @user3531883 This is exactly what the above snippet will do. An `if` condition depending on the view type.

Comment: @user3531883 I added a full example

Comment: You should not access the adapter in the decoration, the adapter point of view may not be what is on screen (see google io talk https://youtu.be/LqBlYJTfLP4?t=2317), keep all necessary information in the view holder (access it with #getChildViewHolder).

Answer (score 4):

Based on @David MedenJak answer, I had made my own Item Decorator for different view types as the answer lag in one condition as it draws decorator above section, if it comes after any normal row,

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.annotation.ColorRes;
import android.support.annotation.DimenRes;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Locale;

import mp.data.modal.MRecyclerListItem;

public class HeaderSimpleDividerDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int                 dividerHeight;
    private Paint               dividerPaint;

    public HeaderSimpleDividerDecoration(Context context, @DimenRes int divider_height, @ColorRes int color) {
        dividerPaint = new Paint();
        dividerPaint.setColor(getColor(context, color));
        dividerHeight = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(divider_height);
    }

    private int getColor(Context context, @ColorRes int drawable) {
        return ContextCompat.getColor(context, drawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if(-1 >= position)
            return;
        int viewType = parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position);

        if (MRecyclerListItem.TYPE_NORMAL == viewType) {
            // outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mHeightDp);
                outRect.bottom = dividerHeight;
        } else
            outRect.setEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int childCount = parent.getChildCount() -1;
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();
        int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
        int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();
        int itemCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount ; i++) {
            View view = parent.getChildAt(i);

            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            int viewType = parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position);

            if (MRecyclerListItem.TYPE_NORMAL == viewType) {
                    int nextItem = position + 1;
                    if(nextItem < itemCount)
                    {
                        int nextViewType = parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(nextItem);
                        if(MRecyclerListItem.TYPE_NORMAL != nextViewType)
                            continue;
                    }

                    float topDraw = view.getBottom();
                    float bottomDraw = view.getBottom() + dividerHeight;

                    c.drawRect(left, topDraw, right, bottomDraw, dividerPaint);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

MRecyclerListItem.TYPE_NORMAL is your view type of normal row(other than header)
call the above in following manager,

```
 mRecyclerview.addItemDecoration(new HeaderSimpleDividerDecoration(context,
            2dp , R.color.view_profile_edit_view));
```

Comment: @from this gist, https://gist.github.com/TheGreat0004/5add8f9d4851c7a99eceec8df3e6348c

Comment: Page not found.

Comment: Thanks, probably it works, at least, contains `getItemViewType()` and comparisons with ViewType.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter code to draw divider for certain view type only that can be easily included in your activity/fragment class:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, linearLayoutManager.getOrientation()) {
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            Drawable d = getDrawable();
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
                int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
                int viewType = parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position);
                
                // Draw divider only for view type 2 (can also put position here to remove for certain positions)
                if(viewType == 2) {
                    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    int top = view.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
                    int bottom = top + d.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    d.setBounds(0, top, parent.getRight(), bottom);
                    d.draw(c);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy people !

Example using 2 `Drawable` separators for Horizontal `ItemSeparator` based on items view type :

```kotlin
override fun getItemOffsets(...) {
    parent.adapter?.let { adapter ->
        val childAdapterPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
            .let { if (it == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return else it }

        rect.right = when (adapter.getItemViewType(childAdapterPosition)) {
            YourAdapter.FIRST_ITEM_ID -> firstSeparator.intrinsicWidth
            YourAdapter.SECOND_ITEM_ID -> secondSeparator.intrinsicWidth
            else -> 0
        }
    }
}

override fun onDraw(...) {
    parent.adapter?.let { adapter ->
        parent.children
            .forEach { view ->
                val childAdapterPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
                    .let { if (it == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return else it }

                when (adapter.getItemViewType(childAdapterPosition)) {
                    CustomAdapter.FIRST_ITEM_ID -> firstSeparator.draw(...)
                    CustomAdapter.SECOND_ITEM_ID -> secondSeparator.draw(...)
                    else -> Unit
                }
            }
    }
}

private fun Drawable.draw(view: View, parent: RecyclerView, canvas: Canvas) = apply {
    val left = view.right
    val top = parent.paddingTop
    val right = left + intrinsicWidth
    val bottom = top + intrinsicHeight - parent.paddingBottom
    bounds = Rect(left, top, right, bottom)
    draw(canvas)
}
```

For more info on `ItemSeparator`, [Here](https://medium.com/@nicolas.duponchel/custom-itemdecoration-3b244de437d9) is the article I wrote to explain how to build your own custom ItemDecoration.